# How do I predict a set of frequently bought items?

Tags: clustering, recommender-system, data-science-model, association-rules, predict

I have a dataset of retail transactions wherein different users buy certain **items** together. For example, a user *A* buys a toothpaste, a toothbrush and a floss at the same time, and a user *B* buys a toothpaste, a shampoo and a soap together.

I'm required to find out **for each item in the dataset** a list of items that are frequently bought together with it. For instance, one may expect that whenever a toothbrush is purchased, a toothpaste can be one of the items that are frequently bought together with it.

I tried to make use of the ***Apriori Algorithm*** but that would only give me sets of items that are bought together or, I'm unaware if it can somehow be modified to predict frequent purchases for **a list of items** in the dataset.

Which other algorithm can I put to use here?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to build a matrix representing how often two items are bough together: $M[i,j]$ is the count of how many times items $i$ and $j$ are bought together (note that you need to fill only a diagonal matrix, since it's symmetric).

From there you can calculate whatever you need: most frequent $B$ item bought with a given item $A$, top most frequent pairs of items in general, etc.

You could also consider the matrix as a graph representation, and use algorithms specific to graphs.